# Install local jar with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I tried to install some local jars with:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

I used:

```
install:install-file –Dfile="C:/Program Files/keydox/jkdx/codecs.jar" 
-DgroupId=keydoxWeb -DartifactId=keydoxWebCodec -Dversion=1.0
```

But I keep getting this error:

> No plugin found for prefix '–Dfile=C' in the current project and in
>   the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
>   available from the repositories [local
>   (C:\Users\KroemerT.m2\repository), central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

I also tried to use `dir /x` to figure out a path with short file names only. But that didn't work too. Also it's not just the "C". Moved the jars to "D" and got the same mistake. What possible way to handle the path do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with dash character before the D letter, try to type it by hand: -Dfile="path-to-file" or try this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:/Program Files/keydox/jkdx/codecs.jar" -DgroupId=keydoxWeb -DartifactId=keydoxWebCodec -Dversion=1.0
```